# Express.js returns a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when trying to delete a row from sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I'm trying to build a basic CRUD API. I got get all parts,  get part by id, and add a part working, but the delete part method is keeps on returning a error. Here is what I got

````
app.delete("/parts/delete/:id", (res, req, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  const db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/parts.db", (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error opening Database " + error.message);
    }
    db.run(`DELETE FROM parts WHERE part_number = ?`, id, (error, row) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
        return;
      }
      res.status(200);
    });
  });

  db.close();
});```
````

Comment: Please update the question with the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the params in callback in wrong order. First is the request, second is the response. Just change the first line to the following:

```
app.delete("/parts/delete/:id", (req, res, next) => {
```

Comment: omg.. I can't believe I over looked that. All my other methods were in the right order..